# Compass set permissions on generated CSS files

Tags: permissions, sass, compass-sass, phing

Very simple, when Compass encounters a new SCSS file it generates a new CSS file. Can I set default permissions for these, as by default it sets them without correct permissions for browsers to read them (gives 403 forbidden errors). If there's a way I can set files to inherit the permissions of their directory that would also be acceptable, as would a way to alter permissions during the copy task in Phing.

Comment: With what user are you running compass? What user:group and permission does your public folder and its subfolders have?

Comment: Compass is being run by an <exec> element in Phing, so I assume it runs as my current user. All working directories and files are owned by me, and the group. The files in the www/ directory are mostly owned by me, standard permissions are 755 but some new created files are owned by www-data with 644.

Comment: Files generated by Sass/Compass have the same permissions as the user who ran the command.  It sounds like Phing is running Compass as the wrong user.  You might get a better answer if you changed your tags, since the problem isn't related to Compass or Sass.

Comment: Is there any way to check what user phing will be running as? I'd assume it will be running as me.

Comment: Hey, M1ke. Did you find a solution? I have the same problem?

Comment: I no longer have this problem but I don't recall a specific solution. This was posted shortly after moving to Ubuntu from Windows and so I was learning a lot about file permissions. Specifically I had issues running `compass` anyway, due to problems with different versions of the `ruby virtual machine (rvm)`. I am presuming that once I got `rvm` running correctly I will have found permissions to be correct on generated files. I also set my `apache2` service to run as my own user, which might also have been the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your development environment is set up, but I use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) to compile my sass files. With grunt you have full control over the build process and can execute scripts after successful building (fx clear frontend caches or set file permissions if necessary).

Markus

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I didn't downvote it but I guess that someone felt it wasn't really relevant, as it's suggesting use of a different technology rather than solving the problem.